# Hacer un javascript en html que me devuelva mi ip

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy haciendo un pequeño html con su javascript para que me muestre mi ip , el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(loading, success){
        var xhr = XMLHttpRequest !== undefined
                    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
                    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

            loading.apply(null, []);
            xhr.open('get', 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4)
                {
                    success.call(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
    }(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('my-ip').innerHTML = 'cargando ip...';
    }, function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById('my-ip').innerHTML = response.ip;
    }));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=get_ip"></script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  mi ip es: <strong id="my-ip"></strong>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Pero no funciona me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en el ejemplo funciono:
http://jsfiddle.net/1ppno3ju/

Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si, lo que pasa es que el script va abajo del del div#mi-ip

Answer (score 1):

```
  <HEAD>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(loading, success){
        var xhr = XMLHttpRequest !== undefined
                    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
                    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

            loading.apply(null, []);
            xhr.open('get', 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4)
                {
                    success.call(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
    }(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('my-ip').innerHTML = 'cargando ip...';
    }, function(response)
    {
        document.getElementById('my-ip').innerHTML = response.ip;
    }));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=get_ip"></script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  mi ip es: <strong id="my-ip"></strong>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```